# "doing that look-away thing" vs "looking away"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, compounds

I found a sentence (in bold) from a children's book called [*Wonder* by R. J. Palacio](https://www.penguin.co.uk/articles/childrens-article/wonder-by-r-j-palacio-extract).

> If I found a magic lamp and I could have one wish, I would wish that I had a normal face that no one ever noticed at all. I would wish that I could walk down the street **without people seeing me and then doing that look-away thing**.

Here is my question.
I thought it could be possible to say "looking away" instead of "doing that look-away thing".
Is this incorrect or unnatural?

Comment: This is a literary way of expressing something. It means looking away probably in a way where the person tries to not be rude or obvious.

Comment: "Looking away" would be the usual way of saying it. The speaker is trying to express that the reaction has become depressingly familiar.

Comment: @KateBunting: I don't see why you say "usual". It's effectively a one-off neologistic usage anyway, so we'd be looking at a tiny sample size to try and establish what people *usually* say. But to *my* ear, plain "look-away" seems much more approriate, because it comes across as an ***imperative*** used "adjectivally" (invoking the image of rubbernecking  passers-by being metaphorically reduced to children being thus instructed by their mother while out walking, as in *"**Don't stare**!"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I meant **without people seeing me and then looking away**, which seems to me the natural way to say it, not at all 'one-off'.

Comment: @KateBunting: I just searched Google Books for "**a look away look**" AND "**a looking away look**". (GB ignores punctuation marks). There was exactly ***one*** match for the former - *Suddenly a curious bracing in the women , **a looking - away look** in the men. And a permanent watchfulness in her mother*. Admittedly, ***no*** relevant matches for the latter, but a sample size of one doesn't tell us anything. Me and you just have different "internal grammarians" (or different "Literary Critic" hats! :)

Comment: ...actually, I just repeated the search with the exact search string here *("**that look away thing**")*. Which found 6 more instances besides the one cited here, but "**that looking away thing**" found just a single written instance. Still not much to go on, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But I never said anything about 'a looking-away look'! I meant **looking away** as opposed to **doing that look-away thing**.

Comment: sorry about that! posting at about the same time sometimes creates a weird thread!

Comment: As @KateBunting has made abundantly clear, "doing a *thing*" implies that it is a common action, or at least *the speaker* believes it's common (a ploy the author might be using to show the psychological state of the speaker), but doesn't know the exact word(s) to describe it. E.G., "The cat did that twitch of the hind end *thing*, whatever it's called, like it's going to pounce!" (might be heard in colloquial dialogue) There are many words in English to use in place of an unknown: whatchamacallit, doohickey, and *thing*. see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whatchamacallit